# OnTokenValidated event not triggered

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft.identity.web

What I'm trying to do is add a claim after authentication. The following example of triggering an `OnTokenValidation` event not actually working.

I'm using `Microsoft.Identity.Web` to authenticate on Azure AD. That part works! How can I register events using `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication` to add custom claims

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(_configuration);
services.Configure<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
                    {
                        var claims = new List<Claim> {
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.OtherPhone, "somevalue")
                        };
                        ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                };
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using AddMicrosoftIdentityWeb**Api**Authentication, so the events that will be triggered are JwtBearerEvents.

You can set them up as below (.NET 6 API):

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration);

// Enable PII for logging
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

// Configure middleware events
builder.Services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
        {
            var accessToken = ctx.SecurityToken;
            Debug.WriteLine("[OnTokenVaidated]: I can do stuff here! ");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnMessageReceived = ctx =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("[OnMessageReceived]: I can do stuff here! ");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnAuthenticationFailed = ctx =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("[OnAuthenticationFailed]: Authentication failed with the following error: ");
            Debug.WriteLine(ctx.Exception);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnChallenge = ctx =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("[OnChallenge]: I can do stuff here! ");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```